# Custom UINavigationBar background image appears darker than the original image

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I am customizing a UINavigationBar like so:

```
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

My original image `background.png` looks like this:

[image: original]

It has a flat color `#4b0367`

The resulting NavigationBar looks like this:

[image: resulting bar]

It has the color `#311253` which is different from the original! 
Apparently UIKit changes the color.

Note:

- Setting `tintColor` had no effect.
- Setting a transparent background image + a color is not an appropriate solution in my case.

Does anybody know how the underlying mechanism works?
How can I get the original image to appear correctly?

Comment: where you kept this one in appdelegate or viewcontroller?

Comment: The code above sits in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, so in AppDelegate.

Comment: You find any solution for it?

Comment: unfortunately, i didn't.