# Set navigation bar image in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationbar, ios7

I want to convert my current project from iOS 6 to iOS 7. 
In iOS 6 my project is working fine, but in iOS 7 navigation bar image is not showing properly.

I used this code snippet for iOS 6,

```
UIImage *imgNav = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation.png"];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:imgNav forBarMetrics:
     UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

How can I set the navigation bar image in iOS 7?

Comment: Thanks for all suggestion.I got the solution of my question but i am not sure this is right way or not. currently it's working for me.

Comment: can anybody give its answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190127/custom-uinavigationbar-background-image-appears-darker-than-the-original-image

Answer (score 31):

Try Adding the below code in AppDelegate

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation.png"] 
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This is the Swift Version:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "navigation.png"), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Swift 3 version :

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "logo-dark.png"), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Comment: Its working if you follow the rules mentioned in ios7 guide to create image which you are going to use as background for navigation bar:  
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ResizableImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH30-SW1

Comment: Just add this onto the 'applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions' method, in the AppDelegate

Answer (score 15):

For iOS 7:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 5):

Use This Simple Syntax for Change `Navigation Background` Easy Way.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] )
{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation.png"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Storyboard Way:

1. Drag an image view onto the bottom bar of the storyboard scene.
2. Control-drag from the navigation item on the left in the scene list to the newly created image view.
3. Click on the image view, and set the image in the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Its working if you follow the rules mentioned in ios7 guide:
    •   If you want a solid color with no gradient, create a 1 x 1 point image. 
    •   If you want a vertical gradient, create an image that has a width of 1 point and a height that matches the height of the UI element’s background. 
    •   If you want to provide a repeating textured appearance, you need to create an image with dimensions that match the dimensions of the repeating portion of the texture. 
    •   If you want to provide a nonrepeating textured appearance, you need to create a static image with dimensions that match the dimensions of the UI element’s background area.

For more Info Please follow the link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ResizableImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH30-SW1

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // This will set the backGround image for all the Navigation Bars

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                                                            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                            UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor],
                                                            UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                                            UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic" size:20.0f]
                                                            }];

 if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
    {


        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigatio_for_ios6"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
else
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x067AB5)];

        // Uncomment to change the color of back button
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        // Uncomment to assign a custom backgroung image
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigon_bg_ios7.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        // Uncomment to change the back indicator image

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

        // Uncomment to change the font style of the title

        NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
        shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];


        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in appDelegate class it will help you.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarimg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```