# UINavigationBar setBackgroundImageForBarMetrics doesn't work in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios7

i'm trying to se an image for the background of the navigation bar, and i'm doing this like i do in iOS6:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

this is the image:

[image]

and this is the result when i run:

[image]

on iOS 6 works perfect, instead on iOS 7 have that problem...

Comment: May be this link could be helpufl:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361500/how-to-set-navigation-bar-image-ins-ios-7

Comment: it's the same i have write above, how can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your navigation Controller:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navbar.png"]];
```