# iOS 7 UINavigationBar appearance not working first time…

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I am trying to change the look of the UINavigationBar in my iOS7 app.  I am doing the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    m_sNumberToCall = @"";

    UIBarButtonItem * btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IconHome.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btHomeTouched:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;


    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TVCNavBack.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    NSShadow * shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                           shadow,
                                                           NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:21.0],
                                                           NSFontAttributeName,
                                                           nil]];
}
```

But, the first time I present the UITableViewController it is the standard iOS7 nav bar, then I press home and present it again and it is my new look.

Any ideas why it does not work the first time?

Comment: try to move code in viewDidAppear

Comment: I did try it there and no go, I also tried it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: For any else who may experience the sam issue, I changed the code from this: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBa… to this: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBa… as well as in the setTitleTextAttributes line.  Found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361500/how-to-set-navigation-bar-image-ins-ios-7

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't change the appearance but the navigation bar directly. The appearance affects only the future instances but not the already created ones.

Change:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TVCNavBack.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

to:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TVCNavBack.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I actually have the same issue and I'm setting appearance before my navigation controller is instantiated...

Comment: That explains a lot !

Comment: The real solution is as answered by @fabf98dev below. You do not need to use navigationController, you just need to make sure that you are calling this line (UINavigationBar.Appear..) before you show your first viewController.

Comment: A Great Answer!

Answer (score 2):

The answer before only helps you with the background image but not with the `title text attributes`.

You don't need to change your code but all you have to do is move it to

`applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

in your `AppDelegate.m` file.