# ios7 UINavigationBar backgroundImage is set upside down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set the UINavigationBar background image:

I added in AppDelegate: (please note that it's one image)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"general-top_bar_with_status.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Since I don't need translucent, in the ViewController in ViewDidLoad I added:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

This is the image:
[image]

Unfortunately this is what I get:
[image]

As you can see, the image is upsite down.

What is wrong?

In storyboard, I set a place for TopBar - Opaque navigation bar

Comment: To me, it looks more like it's shifted downwards (and the color on the top has filled in the remaining area). Try actually making it upside down - the lower portion appears darker (and not lighter as it appears in your image).

Comment: The second image is not exactly the same.

Comment: It's one image. Not sure what happened there

Comment: I set in storyboard the topbar to Opaque Navigation Controller - could this cause the problem?

Comment: can anybody give answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190127/custom-uinavigationbar-background-image-appears-darker-than-the-original-image

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For **iOS 7** you have to use **320x64** size navigation bar image

Comment: In my case there were 2 problems, 1. I was using only 2x size, 2. I was using image name as "detailNavBariPad@2x" in my code including with 2x. Image name in coding should not have 2x in their name.

Comment: what is the dimension of the image ?

Answer (score 2):

make picture 2X Size. with name mynavbar@2x.png

Nav bar is Taking size of its self + status bar size. You may create only navbar size

640X88

or 640X128 for navbar + status bar

Then

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mynavbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```